# How to make several minipages with images be on one page

Tags: graphics, page-breaking, minipage, sweave

Consider the following code

```
\noindent Some text here

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \hspace{-30pt}
  \includegraphics[width=300pt]{img1}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \hspace{-15pt}
  \includegraphics[width=300pt]{img2}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \hspace{-30pt}
  \includegraphics[width=300pt]{img3}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \hspace{-15pt}
  \includegraphics[width=300pt]{img4}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \hspace{-30pt}
  \includegraphics[width=300pt]{img5}
\end{minipage}
```

The problem several of such blocks (i.e. text with some number of images) are being generated dynamicaly. And I need to have each block on one page (if there's not enough room for block one page the whole block is placed on next page).

The natural solution for that is `minipage` or `figure` but after I wrap that all in minipage the whole layout is broken!

What is the solution for my problem?

And yes, I'm sure that in any case the block will not have too many images, so that any block can be placed into blank page.

Comment: please extend your code snippet to small, complete document beginning with`\documentclass{...} and ending with `\end{document}`. claryfy, what you mean with "dynamicaly" generated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided a usable test example, but the repeated minipage do not seem to be doing a lot since the `\includegraphics` are all fixed width anyway so perhaps

```
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\raggedright
 \includegraphics[width=300pt]{img1}
 \includegraphics[width=300pt]{img2}
 \includegraphics[width=300pt]{img3}
 \includegraphics[width=300pt]{img4}
 \includegraphics[width=300pt]{img5}
\end{minipage}
```